# Stationarity conditions in Pyomo

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

I am trying to implement MCP (Mixed Complementarity Problem) problem in `pyomo` with `PATH` solver, and I found a way how to write complementarity conditions. I use `pyomo.mpec` and `ComplementarityList` component, in which we directly indicate constraint itself and dual variable. But I am a little bit in doubt about the stationarity condition. Should it be just implemented as an equality constraint?

Because, for example, in `GAMS`, when you formulate stationarity condition you **explicitly** indicate equality expression and with respect to which variable you took a derivative like `equality_equation.variable` in `model\....\`.

And also when I define just an equality constraint, I explicitly indicate its dual variable in `GAMS` like `equality_constraint.its_dual_variable`.

Does it have to be done in `pyomo` in some way? Or it doesn't make any difference even mathematically, since it is just equality?

Comment: I have never worked with `MPEC` component in `pyomo`, bu tI guess you may check the [MPEC paper](https://cfwebprod.sandia.gov/cfdocs/CompResearch/docs/pyomo_mpec_sandreport.pdf) Published by Hart et all as report for the including of MPEC component in `Pyomo`

Comment: Thanks for the paper! I have just tested on a small problem and it turned out, that it is enough just to use equalities to define stationary conditions